# Android - Acra doesn't report

Tags: java, android, acra

I'trying to use ACRA as bug reporter, I added *acra-4.6.1.jar* to my project and made this class

**ReportApp.java**

```
package org.qtproject.example.ourmessenger;

import org.acra.*;
import org.acra.annotation.*;
import org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication;
import android.app.Application;



@ReportsCrashes(
    formUri = "http://######/#####/######/####.php",
    formUriBasicAuthLogin = "root",
    formUriBasicAuthPassword = "#######",
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
    forceCloseDialogAfterToast = false, 
    resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text
    )
public class ReportApp extends Application  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

Then , I edited my android:name on AndroidManifest:

**AndoridManifest.xml**

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="org.qtproject.example.ourmessenger.ReportApp" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

Also I added this line in the end of AndroidManifest.xml before `</manifest>`:

```
 <CheckBoxPreference android:key="acra.enable" android:title="@string/pref_enable_acra" android:summaryOn="@string/pref_acra_enabled" android:summaryOff="@string/pref_acra_disabled" android:defaultValue="true"/>
```

and I use this

```
String i=null;
i.contains("kj");
```

for testing ACRA. Actually it doesn't work. I'm not added anything to mainActivity.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 .
 .
public class MainActivity extends QtActivity implements SensorEventListener
{
    .
    .
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        SharedPreferences appPref = getSharedPreferences("isFirstRun", 0);
        boolean isFirstRun = appPref.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);
        .
        .

    }
     .
     .
}
```

It's not only doesn't show any TOAST message but also doesn't report to server.Any suggestion?

Comment: CheckBoxPref doesn't belong in AndroidManifest, it belongs in your Preferences xml. And you need to be explicit "it doesn't work" tells us nothing. State exactly what you are doing and what output you see. What does your logcat say?

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the request type in @ReportsCrashes for your targeted service. For your `formUri = "http://######/#####/######/####.php"`service which is essentially either a POST or PUT service, add `httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.POST` or `httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT` in @ReportsCrashes block.

See the [doc](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#postput-request) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added this line but still it doesn't work .

Comment: I just run your code and it worked just as expected. Toast is there and if I add the `mailTo` option in @ReportCrashes block, it prompted for email as well. Even I put the same lib version just to be on safe side. Could you create another test project and try running your code there? I'm beginning to believe it might be something else that's playing the role of culprit here.

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to use ACRA with a qt-android project, and it doesn't report anything as well, whether I call abort() or force an error elsewhere.

I see that it initializes correctly, but when I force a crash I just get the regular Android crash message and no toast nor email.

`I/qtVlmApp(22971): onCreate qtVlmApp
D/ACRA    (22971): ACRA is enabled for org.meltemus.qtvlm, initializing...
D/ACRA    (22971): Using default Mail Report Fields
W/ACRA    (22971): org.meltemus.qtvlm reports will be sent by email (if accepted by user).
D/ACRA    (22971): Looking for error files in /data/data/org.meltemus.qtvlm/files
I/Qt      (22971): qt start
I/QtPositioning(22971): Positioning start
.....
.....
F/libc    (22971): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xb9ce2008 in tid 7981 (Thread (pooled))`

Maybe Acra cannot work in an android-qt application (c++) ?